# add value on top array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
 $arr = array(
        "Posts" => "post", 
        "Projects" => "project"
 );
```

I want to add new element `"News" => "new"` to `$arr` on top with the same format, I have tried with below

```
 $new_element = array("News" => "new");
 array_unshift($arr, $new_element);
```

but I got

```
     Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( [News] => news ) 
       [Posts] => post
       [Projects] => project 
    )
```

They don't have the same format, please give advice. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this..

```
$arr = array(
        "Posts" => "post", 
        "Projects" => "project"
 );

$new_element = array("News" => "new");

$arr = $new_element + $arr;
print_r($arr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [News] => new
    [Posts] => post
    [Projects] => project
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add it by:

```
$arr['News'] = "new";
```

Then sort your array keys.

```
ksort($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge):

```
$arr = array(
    "Posts"    => "post",
    "Projects" => "project"
);

$new_element = array("News" => "new");

$arr = array_merge($arr, $new_element);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [Posts] => post
    [Projects] => project
    [News] => new
)
```

---

**Note:** But be aware that when your source array has the same key, it will be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)
if you want to add it at first try this:

```
$new_arr = array_merge(array("News" => "new"),  $arr);
```

if you want to add it at last try this:

```
$new_arr = array_merge($arr, array("News" => "new"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(
    "Posts" => "post", 
    "Projects" => "project"
);
$arr["News"] = 'new';
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(
        "Posts" => "post", 
        "Projects" => "project"
 );

$new_element = array("News" => "new");


$someArray=$new_element+$arr;


print_r($someArray);
```

using + we can insert key value pair array in the top of the existing array

Comment: It would help if you explain more on how and where to use your code

Comment: The above code is used to insert the key value pair element in the top of the array.